# Metadata navigation on document library, removing "Folders" from the TreeView

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Does anyone know how to add only one custom `MetadataNavigationHierarchy`? 
In my case, I would like to remove **Folders** from the TreeView, so my custom `MetadataNavigationHierarchy` is the only one being displayed.

I'm currently working on a Console application that's setting up Metadata navigation on an existing SharePoint 2013 document library containing existing folders and files.

Everything is working as it's supposed to, but I would like to remove **Folders** from the navigation.

Working code I use to add my custom value **Tema**:

```
MetadataNavigationSettings mdnSettings = MetadataNavigationSettings.GetMetadataNavigationSettings(list);    

if (taxonomyField != null)
{
    MetadataNavigationHierarchy hierarchyToAdd = new MetadataNavigationHierarchy(taxonomyField);

    if (null == mdnSettings.FindConfiguredHierarchy(taxonomyField.TermSetId))
    {
        mdnSettings.AddConfiguredHierarchy(hierarchyToAdd);
    }
}
else
{
    Helper.WriteError("Could not find Tema taxonomy field");
}

MetadataNavigationSettings.SetMetadataNavigationSettings(list, mdnSettings, true);
list.RootFolder.Update();
```

`taxonomyField` is the `TermSet` **Tema** I would like to display.

After the code runs, the "Selected Hierarchy Fields" are **Tema** and **Folders**. If I remove **Folders** manually in the GUI, everything workes like it's supposed to.

I've tried to use `mdnSettings.ClearConfiguredHierarchies();` first, to remove **Folders**. This sets up the correct fields in "Library Settings --> Metadata Navigation Settings", but does not display the Metadata navigation when viewing the document library. If I click "Ok" on "Metadata Navigation Settings", **Folders** is added automatically, and both **Tema** and **Folders** is displayed in the document library. And again, if i remove **Folders**, then click "Ok" everything works as I want it to.

Visual representation of **Folders**, which i would like to remove programmatically.
[image: Do not want "Folders" here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MetadataNavigationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.metadatanavigation.metadatanavigationsettings(v=office.14).aspX) contains `FolderHierarchy` hierarchy for that purpose, the attribute `HideFoldersNode` defines whether  to remove or add Folder hierarchy field:

```
<FolderHierarchy HideFoldersNode=\"True\" />
```

But for some reason(!) [MetadataNavigationSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.metadatanavigation.metadatanavigationsettings(v=office.14).aspX) does not expose that property, it is declared as an **internal** property.

### How to add/remove Folder hierarchy field using SharePoint OM

The following method demonstrates how to *bypass* this limitation and allows to set `HideFoldersNode` property of [MetadataNavigationSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.metadatanavigation.metadatanavigationsettings(v=office.14).aspX):

```
public class MetadataNavigationSettingsHelper
{
    public static void SetHideFoldersNode(MetadataNavigationSettings settings,bool value)
    {
        var t = settings.GetType();
        t.InvokeMember("HideFoldersNode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance, null, settings, new object[] { value });
    }
}
```

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to add taxonomy field into navigation hierarchy and **remove** `Folder` field:

```
private static void AddTaxonomyFieldToHierarchy(SPList list, TaxonomyField taxonomyField)
{
     MetadataNavigationSettings mdnSettings = MetadataNavigationSettings.GetMetadataNavigationSettings(list);
     MetadataNavigationSettingsHelper.SetHideFoldersNode(mdnSettings,true);  //remove Folder

     MetadataNavigationHierarchy hierarchyToAdd = new MetadataNavigationHierarchy(taxonomyField);
     if (null == mdnSettings.FindConfiguredHierarchy(taxonomyField.Id))
     {
         mdnSettings.AddConfiguredHierarchy(hierarchyToAdd);
     }
     MetadataNavigationSettings.SetMetadataNavigationSettings(list, mdnSettings, true);
}
```